# Select media popup is not opening after upgrade ckeditor from 4 to 5 Drupal

Tags: javascript, media

We have drupal version 9.5.7 in our website, When we had upgrade ckeditor4 to ckeditor5 then Select media popup(for image and video) is not opening.

Console error: ajax.js?v=9.5.7:411 An error occurred during the execution of the Ajax response: TypeError: $element.dialog is not a function

[image]

When I click on add media button then select media popup is not opening, Please help me to fix it, thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be reported as a bug to the maintainers with steps to reproduce.

Comment: @cilefen thanks, Is there any other option to tackle this ?